# How to disable IR receiver

Tags: xorg, remote

I'm running Ubuntu on a mid 2009 iMac, which has an IR receiver built in. Every time I use the remote for my Apple TV which is seated right next to the computer, the computer responds to the remote. As far as I can tell, the up and down arrows control volume, while the left and right buttons seem to control back and forward pages in firefox. I know there used to be a way to fix this by editing the xorg.conf file, but it doesn't seem like you can edit xorg.conf like you used to be able to. Any ideas on how to stop this?

Comment: You could cover the sensor with a piece of tape.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does not directly answer your question but is the much easier solution.

The easiest solution here is to just cover up the IR receiver - the IR beams won't be able to penetrate tape or paper put over the IR sensor.  That saves the headache of actually having to disable the sensor in system settings or by blacklisting drivers you may later want.